# UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password) stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to make a very simple implementation of an `IUserStore` that would essentially:

- use NHibernate
- save users in a single table (no claims/logins)
- store role names in the same table, in an nvarchar column (pipe (`'|'`) 
  separated if multiple items).

When I run the following method:

```
[Fact]
public void Create_A_User()
{
    // _session is a valid NHibernate ISession object
    using (var userStore = new SimpleUserStore<SimpleIdentityUser>(_session))
    using (var userManager = new UserManager<SimpleIdentityUser>(userStore))
    {
        var user = new SimpleIdentityUser
        {
            UserName = "kenny_mccormick",
            RolesStr = "admin",
        };

        var createTask = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "the_password");

        var result = createTask.Result; // this never finishes...
    }
}
```

the last line would never finish executing.

The weird thing is that the `UserManager` never calls any of the functions in my `SimpleUserStore`; it gets stuck before that.

Here are the components I defined:

#### The user class:

```
public class SimpleIdentityUser : IUser
{
    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string RolesStr { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Id
    {
        get { return UserId.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

#### The User Store:

```
public class SimpleUserStore<TUser> :
    IUserPasswordStore<TUser>,
    IUserRoleStore<TUser>,
    IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>
    where TUser : SimpleIdentityUser
{
    // ReSharper disable once StaticFieldInGenericType
    private static readonly Task EmptyTask = new Task(() => { });

    private readonly ISession _session;

    public SimpleUserStore(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public Task<TUser> FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
    {
        return Task.FromResult((TUser) null);
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        _session.Save(user);
        return EmptyTask;
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        // updates will (hopefully) be saved automatically when the current session is committed
        return EmptyTask;
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(TUser user)
    {
        _session.Delete(user);
        return EmptyTask;
    }

    public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        TUser user = null;
        Guid guidId;

        if (Guid.TryParse(userId, out guidId))
            user = _session.Get<TUser>(guidId);

        return Task.FromResult(user);
    }

    public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        TUser user = _session.Query<TUser>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
        return Task.FromResult(user);
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        return EmptyTask;
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash != null);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public Task AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)
    {
        new SimpleRoleManager<TUser>(user).AddRole(role);

        return EmptyTask;
    }

    public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)
    {
        new SimpleRoleManager<TUser>(user).DeleteRole(role);

        return EmptyTask;
    }

    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
    {
        List<string> roles = new SimpleRoleManager<TUser>(user).GetRoles().ToList();

        return Task.FromResult((IList<string>) roles);
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new SimpleRoleManager<TUser>(user).IsInRole(role));
    }

    public Task SetSecurityStampAsync(TUser user, string stamp)
    {
        user.SecurityStamp = stamp;
        return EmptyTask;
    }

    public Task<string> GetSecurityStampAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.SecurityStamp);
    }
}
```

#### How I manage roles

Probably not so important, but here it is anyway:

```
public class SimpleRoleManager<TUser> where TUser : SimpleIdentityUser
{
    private const string Separator = "|";

    private readonly TUser _user;

    public SimpleRoleManager(TUser user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public string[] GetRoles()
    {
        return (_user.RolesStr ?? String.Empty)
            .Split(Separator.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string roleName)
    {
        return GetRoles().Contains(roleName);
    }

    public bool AddRole(string roleName)
    {
        var roles = GetRoles().ToList();

        if (roles.Contains(roleName))
            return false;

        roles.Add(roleName);
        SetRoles(roles);
        return true;
    }

    public bool DeleteRole(string roleName)
    {
        List<string> roles = GetRoles().ToList();

        if (!roles.Contains(roleName))
            return false;

        roles.Remove(roleName);
        SetRoles(roles);
        return true;
    }

    private void SetRoles(IEnumerable<string> roles)
    {
        _user.RolesStr = String.Join(Separator, roles);
    }
}
```

I have been inspecting the `UserManager<TUser>` class with DotPeek, but found no obvious causes for this weird behavior.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach to async is fundamentally broken at the moment, because you're returning the same task for *all* operations... and never starting it. I don't see any "infinite loop" here - I just see you blocking on a task which can never complete.

It's not clear what you hope to accomplish with your `EmptyTask` task, but it's definitely *not* helping you at the moment.

Furthermore, it's not clear that your code is really asynchronous in any aspect, unless `_session.Save` (etc) are really asynchronous.

You could improve things *somewhat* by just running extra tasks, e.g.

```
public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    Action action = () => _session.Save(user);
    return Task.Run(action);
}
```

... although the fact that you're then immediately blocking on the task in the calling code makes it pointless, too. (It's not even clear how this compiles at the moment, as `Task` doesn't have a `Result` property... only `Task<T>` does.)

As noted in comments, this will create a new task which will effectively run synchronously in a new thread - using more threads than you'd otherwise need, with the *potential* benefit of parallelism. It doesn't achieve the same goals as a properly asynchronous database call (where there wouldn't be *any* threads tied up for the save call - just a task which would complete when the relevant network response was returned).

If you don't really care about it being asynchronous, you can use:

```
public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    _session.Save(user);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

This will *synchronously* save (just like your current code does) but then return a completed task (rather than the task which will never complete, as per your current code).

Comment: Wow, that really was a stupid mistake on my part; thanks a lot for clearing that up.

Comment: The code compiles because `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password)` returns a `Task<IdentityResult>`.

Comment: @w0lf: Ah, so that's not the CreateUser method that we can see... Slightly confusing.

Comment: yes, this indirection is specific to ASP.NET Identity - you interact with a `UserManager` object that uses your `IUser*Store` to persist users, roles, logins, etc.

Comment: @w0lf @JonSkeet  return Task.Run(action); is not the right way if its a web app. If you use it like that than it can cause thread starvation. Bacause when IIS gets a request it asks CLR for a thread, it then pulls one from the threadpool. When you Task.Run, it also pulls a thread from the threadpool. This is what should happen: thread should be returned to the CLR threadpool, and then the OS should interrupt the CLR to get a new thread whenever its task is complete. At this particular case, what should be done is this: `_session.Save(user); return Task.FromResult<object>(null);`

Comment: @KemalGültekin: Well that's not asynchronous at all, is it? While I take your point that wrapping synchronous calls in tasks can be problematic, it can still be a reasonable approach if this is basically trying to achieve parallelism. (For example, while the user is being saved, another call can be made.) The use of `Task.Result` in the sample code is broken (IMO), and it would be much better to have genuinely asynchronous DB calls (rather than tying up a task and therefore a thread), but I wouldn't go as far as a blanket "not the right way" statement.

Comment: @KemalGültekin: But I'll add a note on my answer anyway :)

Comment: @Jon Yes saying not right is not right. You have made my point clearer in your comment :)

Comment: @KemalGültekin: Excellent - it's always good to come to agreement on this sort of thing :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: nHibernate's `Session.Save` isn't asynchronous and even more important: Sessions are not thread safe. Depending on what actions might be executed in parallel calling `Task.Run(() => _session.Save(user))` might nevertheless be "not the right way" - but for a different reason.
I even doubt that asynchrony was an actual goal of the code. The question probably only came up because the `IUserRoleStore<TUser>` interface requires to implement `CreateAsync` thus forcing you to "fake" asynchrony.

Comment: @pescolino: Ick. All kinds of problems then. It's hard to know what can be salvaged in that case, to be honest :(